# Google Maps .getMap() deprecated

Tags: java, android, gradle, maps

I am using Google Maps on my Android App. Before a gradle the new version of Google Play Services it works with the following code to get the Fragment:

```
GoogleMap googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Since I updated to version 9.2.1, the .getMap() is red (deprecated). Is there a new practise to declare the fragment?

Thank you for every response?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should replace getMap() with getMapAsync().

As per the official doc, get map async requires a callback and this is where you do main google maps stuff. Have a look on the below snippet.

```
 public class MapPane extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
//DO WHATEVER YOU WANT WITH GOOGLEMAP
 map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        map.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: It should be noted that today the `MapFragment` `getFragmentManager()` is deprecated. The solution is to make use of `getSupportFragmentManager()`, as mentioned  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51737667/since-the-android-getfragmentmanager-api-is-deprecated-is-there-any-alternati) and [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start?hl=es-419).

Answer (score 1):

[`getMapAsync()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)) looks like a good fit. You would have to adapt your implementation though. The call is asynchronous and you won't have the map immediately. On the other hand you won't have issues because of the map not being loaded when you start using it.