# Since the Android getFragmentManager() API is deprecated, is there any alternative?

Tags: java, android

`FragmentManager` is deprecated. Is there an alternative or what can I do now?

```
 PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                destination = place.getName().toString();
                destinationLatLng = place.getLatLng();
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
            }
        });
```

[image: deprecation strike image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a look here for how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @VicJordan: please don't add "home-made tags" into titles; we discourage that here, since we have a proper tagging system. Natural and grammatical sentences are better, either in statement or question form. Here is [the canonical discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253028/why-is-removing-tags-from-the-title-suggested-so-often). (Please follow this advice for your own question titles too, thanks!).

Comment: Just use: `getParentFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 57):

This method was deprecated in API level 28.

Use `FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: I think this answer is outdated - it is simply `getSupportFragmentManager()` now

Comment: @kc_dev There is no getSupportFragmentManager() in Fragment of AndroidX. The deprecation message says you have to use getParentFragmentManager(). Fragmentmanagers are pretty much the biggest crap in Android since fragments were introduced. :)

Answer (score 53):

If I understood you well `getFragmentManager()` is now deprecated

we will use `getChildFragmentManager()`
Return a private FragmentManager for placing and managing Fragments inside of this Fragment.

we will use `getParentFragmentManager()`
Return the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated with this fragment's activity.

so, if you deal with fragments inside a fragment you will use the first one and if you deal with fragments inside an activity you will use the second one.

you can find them here `package androidx.fragment.app;`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getFragmentManager()

Comment: Refer here for including the package: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#declaring_dependencies

Comment: +1. I tested both `getChildFragmentManager()` and `getParentFragmentManager()` for a fragment popup inside of another fragment (i.e. Bottom Sheet Fragment inside of another fragment), but both are working without any error! Do you the reason of that?

Answer (score 25):

If you using AndroidX Fragment `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` you can use

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
```

Comment: Nowadays you should use requireActivity() .

Answer (score 14):

Right now, in Kotlin I use

```
val fragmentManager = this@className.parentFragmentManager
```

or (prefer this one)

```kotlin
val fragmentManager = this@className.childFragmentManager
```

well if you still use Java I think the code is

```
FragmentManager manager = this.getParentFragmentManager();
```

Hope my answer can solve the task.

I recommended you to use Navigation now

Answer (score 12):

I used `parentFragmentManager` instead of `fragmentManager`.
(If you are using *androidx* `Fragment`.)

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.2.0

> **getFragmentManager() deprecation**: The `getFragmentManager()` and
>   `requireFragmentManager()` methods on `Fragment` have been deprecated and
>   replaced with a single `getParentFragmentManager()` method, which
>   returns the non-null `FragmentManager` the `Fragment` is added to (you can
>   use `isAdded()` to determine if it is safe to call).

Answer (score 10):

Since the question is a little broad, here's the solution for those who have migrated to `androidX`.

Make sure that your fragments are using androidX versions in `import` section. i.e if you're using `DialogFragment()`, replace

```
import android.app.DialogFragment
```

**with**

```
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment
```

Then for `fragmentManager` when `show()`ing the dialog, if launching from another `fragment` don't change it, but if passing from an `Activity`, first extend the activity from `FragmentActivity()`, then pass `supportFragmentManager`:

```
// kotlin
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity

class MyActivity: FragmentActivity() {
    ...
    val myDialog = MyDialog()
    myDialog.show(supportFragmentManager, TAG)
    ...
}
```

***Although,*** the same steps also apply to `support.v4` if you've not migrated to `androidX`. Just in the first step replace

```
import android.app.DialogFragment
```

with

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

Comment: Just a note, AppCompatActivity extends FragmentActivity, so you can use that too.

Answer (score 8):

You should use the Fragment class from Android Support library instead.

[android.app.Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment) was deprecated in API level 28.
Use the Support Library Fragment for consistent behavior across all devices and access to Lifecycle.

Use [android.support.v4.app.Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment) instead.

Answer (score 5):

for Kotlin:

```
activity
    ?.supportFragmentManager
    ?. <whatever needs to come after that>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/) overcome this issue.

As per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment) Fragment class has been deprecated:

> This class was deprecated in API level 28. Use the Support Library
>   Fragment for consistent behavior across all devices and access to
>   Lifecycle.

Answer (score 4):

Use This

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

Instead of

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
```

And 
Use This

```
FragmentManager manager = ((YourActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Instead of

```
 FragmentManager manager = ((YourActivity) mContext).getFragmentManager();
```

Answer (score 0):

Xml

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment"
/>
```

Activity

```
SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
```

Comment: from what class do you call this `getSupportFragmentManager()` ? Please give a bit more of a detailed example

Answer (score 0):

If you're displaying a DialogFragment over a **PreferenceFragment** (specifically an **`android.preference.PreferenceFragment`** not the class from the Support Preference library), then you will see this warning.

Approximately June 2018, Google deprecated the PreferenceFragment and all its associated methods like `getFragmentManager()`. You probably already know that `getSupportFragmentManager()` cannot be used on the PreferenceFragment anyway, as it's a special exception.

The recommended approach now is to use the **PreferenceFragmentCompat** from the AndroidX Jetpack library or from the Preference Support library:

```
implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0"
```

You can see available versions here: https://maven.google.com -> Search for "preference"

More info here: [Android- deprecated method warning regarding PreferenceActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756457/android-deprecated-method-warning-regarding-preferenceactivity#51149808)

---

Be aware that migrating to PreferenceFragmentCompat may be a lengthy and difficult task, especially if you have custom Preference classes. More info:

- [How do I create custom preferences using android.support.v7.preference library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621403/how-do-i-create-custom-preferences-using-android-support-v7-preference-library)
- https://github.com/jaredrummler/ColorPicker/issues/26#issuecomment-331626888
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119256512
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124153118
- [Android: How to remove margin/padding in Preference Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509369/android-how-to-remove-margin-padding-in-preference-screen)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `getFragmentManager()` with `parentFragmentManager` .

Answer (score -2):

Extend **AppCompatActivity** which by default extends **FragmentActivity**, then you can use **getSupportFragmentManager()** which will return you the **fragmentManager**.