# what to replace deprecated getFragmentManager() method with (API 28)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, preferenceactivity, fragmentmanager

I have an Android application I've been working on, min sdk = 21. In it, I use a custom PreferenceActivity that in turn calls a PreferenceFragment. However, after recently updating to API 28, I noticed that the getFragmentManager() method has been deprecated. I skimmed through the [relevant Android Developers page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment/%22Fragment%20%7C%20Android%20Developers%22) where I learnt that the Fragment class has been deprecated, or something of the sort. For clarity, my PreferencesActivity class code is as follows:

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity{
static int layout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        boolean isDark = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("darkTheme", false);
        if (isDark) setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Dark_NoActionBar_BlendStatusBar);
        layout = isDark? R.style.AlertDialogCustom_Dark: R.style.AlertDialogCustom;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // TODO: 08/09/2018 Deprecated
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new PreferencesFragment()).commit();
}

    public static class PreferencesFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        // Preferences code here...
    }
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/51737667/6401241

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you are correct. getFragmentManager and android.app.Fragment were deprecated in API 28.
Instead now we should use Fragment from support library and getSupportFragmentManager respectively.

But if you are worried about those deprecations then you should also note that [PreferenceFragments](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment) too were deprecated in API 28.

Instead, you should use [PreferenceFragmentCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat)

Comment: I'll try this out and get back to you