# Using fragmentManager in RecyclerView adapter click event

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener, fragmentmanager, androidx

With the deprecation of `FragmentManager`, Android Studio desn't provide any code suggestions for the deprecated code.

The problem is `fragmentManager` in `val manager = (holder.itemView.context as Activity).fragmentManager` as it returns this error:

```sh
'getter for fragmentManager: FragmentManager!' is deprecated. Deprectaed in Java
```

I'm already using `import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment`  but the issuee still doesn't go away. Also, I've already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51737667/since-the-android-getfragmentmanager-api-is-deprecated-is-there-any-alternati), but it's not clear on what should be used instead in Kotlin.

```java
holder.myButton.setOnClickListener {
    val dialog = MyDialogFragment()
    val manager = (holder.itemView.context as Activity).fragmentManager
    dialog.show(manager, "example")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getFragmentManager()), you should get the [support manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentActivity#getsupportfragmentmanager) instead. You'll just have to cast the `context` to `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`, like this:

```
val manager = (holder.itemView.context as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager
```

---

EDIT: Make sure that `MyDialogFragment` extends `androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment`, not `android.app.DialogFragment`. Your Activity should also extend `AppCompatActivity` (or at least `FragmentActivity`) to make it work correctly.